# In Python, fastest way to create all possible combinations of replacing up to N positions in a list with a character

Tags: python

I have a specific use case where I need to create every combination of a list containing strings, replacing up to N elements with a specific character. Currently I am generating every single possible combination, and then filtering for which combinations have less than N elements replaced, which is not very effective.

```
 from itertools import product,repeat

 l = ["A","B","C"]
 n = 2

 l_combs = list(set(product(*zip(l, repeat('')))))
```

`l_combs` now contains
`[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', ''), ('A', '', ''), ('', '', 'C'), ('', 'B', 'C'), ('', 'B', ''), ('', '', ''), ('A', '', 'C')]`

```
l_wanted= [x for x in l_combs if x.count('') <= n)]
```

`l_wanted` now contains
`[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', ''), ('A', '', ''), ('', '', 'C'), ('', 'B', 'C'), ('', 'B', ''), ('A', '', 'C')]`

And if the list `l` contains many elements, this can be very in efficient.

What would be an effective way to generate all combinations replacing elements up to N times in a list of generic length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the behavior of `itertools.combinations`, choosing up to `n` indices to replace items at from the total number of indices, i.e. the length of the list `l`. Map the combinations of indices to sets for efficient lookups while outputting:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = ["A", "B", "C"]
n = 2

l_wanted = [
    ['' if i in c else v for i, v in enumerate(l)]
    for k in range(n + 1) for c in map(set, combinations(range(len(l)), k))
]
```

`l_wanted` becomes:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['', 'B', 'C'], ['A', '', 'C'], ['A', 'B', ''], ['', '', 'C'], ['', 'B', ''], ['A', '', '']]
```